# Can you have a half of any array?

Tags: java, arrays, int

Hey guys probably a dumb question but can you have halve of an array?
For example,

```
float g[] = new float [5/2];
```

The compiler runs but I don't understand how you can have an array that is 2.5 in length...

Comment: Because it's integer division. 5 / 2 is 2, not 2.5.

Comment: Impossible. Number of elements is only integer

Comment: "How you can have an array that is 2.5 in length?" -> You can't. Will you store a half-value in your array? It is illogic.

Comment: Did you try running as `float g[] = new float[5.0/2];` ?

Comment: You can also verify it yourself, try printing the result of 5/2.

Comment: none of the comments above makes sense, even your question... what is the half of this array [2, 1, 0]???? would be [0,1] or even more crazy [1, 0.5, 0]???? the half of the array is a new array of the size divided by 2....